# Parthenogenesis in Bees

Tags: reproduction

Parthenogenesis is defined as:

"A type of asexual reproduction in which egg develops without fertilization to form a new individual."

If parthenogenesis takes place in bees, a drone or male bee is produced.

My question is that parthenogenesis is the development of EGG into new individual so, how can egg be developed into male because egg won't have that "Y" chromosome required for male offspring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the "Y chromosome" has nothing to do with sex determination in bees.  Instead, the number of X chromosomes determines the sex.  With only one X chromosome, the egg will develop into a male.  This is called a [haplodiploid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplodiploidy) system of sex determination (the male bees are haploid, having only half the number of chromosomes).

EDIT: I should add that there are *many* systems of sex determination, not just XY or the haplodiploid system.  See the [Z-W system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZW_sex-determination_system) (males are ZZ and females are ZW), the [X0 system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X0_sex-determination_system) (the males are *diploid* for all but the sex chromosome), and [temperature-dependent system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature-dependent_sex_determination) of sex determination.

Comment: @MuhammadRafique: I have edited my answer to be slightly more accurate and provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The Cape honey bee in South Africa can create female offspring without the queen being mated. Female stick insects can also produce female offspring without males, all daughters will however be clones of the mother. I guess this is a last resort to ensure survival in difficult times until a male is found to mate with.

Comment: can you add some references to this?